# MERN Blog: Adding myself as only admin with userContext?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, authentication

I have pretty much finished creating my own personal blog using the MERN stack. I am interested in deploying to have my first function live web app. I want to be the only admin to have Create, Update and Destroy functionality on my blog with eventual functionality of user creating comments, the former is my primary focus.

code is available [here](https://github.com/ambibma/ambiBlog)

More information: Auth is handled via JWT in Express backend. And user is set with a profile storing the JWT with cookies.

Another approach I thought of is just removing the register functionlity and register endpoints and giving myself the only log in, but if I want to give myself options if I want to scale it adding userRoles with the userContext I think would be a good idea.

Overall I could really just use some guidance or just a point in the right direction would be awesome, as there is so much documentation out there. I just want a simple deployed blog for myself with some okay protection so it doesn't get hacked. Thank you so much.

Bonus: Also seeking services to deploy the server and front end, very open to recs

Comment: Can't you just add yourself to the database directly?

Comment: MongoDB suggests you handle auth with Node and express using their-party auth libraries or JWTs

Comment: You should still handle the authentication, just don't create register form

Comment: @Konrad I mean yeah, however in mongodb it just creates a user's table in a collection, not really access to the db. Unless there are methods from mongoose that I am using for initialization I can use and I'm missing.

Comment: @Konrad and yeah when I deploy it Im going to remove the registering functionality.